# Giving control of my units

Tags: starcraft-2

How do I give control of my units to another player?

I was very much surprised when a teammate gave me control of his units somehow, and didn't have time to ask him how he did it. It's a neat feature!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is an icon in the top right that looks like two people. Click it and it will let you set up alliances and control.

[image: image:]

Comment: What is the keyboard shortcut to toggle player control?