# when an ally leaves a game can you control their units?

Tags: starcraft-2

so I played a 4v4, and right at the start of the game, 2 of my allies quit out right at the start.  we ended up winning anyway, and as I was watching the replay, I noticed that 1 of the 2 allies who quit out actually built quite a few things.  I figured that the other ally of ours was actually occasionally going over and building stuff.  But really no idea.

I posted the replay here:  just remove the .rar from it.

http://www.thfonline.com/stuff/m2v4.sc2Replay.rar

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do workers work when I gain control of them?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9647/how-do-workers-work-when-i-gain-control-of-them)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quoted from my answer to [How do workers work when I gain control of them?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9647/how-do-workers-work-when-i-gain-control-of-them/9651#9651):

> **When you get control of someone's
>   units because they've left the game,**
>   you can command their units and buildings as you like (attack, lift off, change rally points, use energy, etc), and you
>   can also spend minerals and gas. You
>   can build buildings, train troops,
>   etc. The resources come out of your
>   bank, but this is because when the
>   ally leaves, their resources are split
>   among remaining allies, and their
>   further income gets split among you
>   too.
>
> Although you are spending "your"
>   resources, the buildings and troops
>   remain that player's for gameplay
>   purposes. Pylons will make energy
>   fields for them, not you. Depots will
>   raise their supply cap, not yours (and
>   they can be supply capped even if
>   you're not).
>
> **Applications:**
>
> - If an ally drops early, make sure to send their workers harvesting, and train more. It will cost you some minerals, but you will get lots back from the split harvest.
> - If an ally drops late, you can basically take over for them, building bases and troops and waging war. At the very least, you can add their remaining troops to your army.

Comment: thanks.  I looked at related posts before I asked but didn't see that part of your answer.  not sure if this should be closed or deleted as duplicate.....

Comment: @Hurrikan I think closed as duplicate is better than deleting. Close as duplicate means the question still exists for searching and even links back to the original. You didn't find that post, but someone may find your post and then be linked back to the original post.

Comment: I thought of voting-to-close, but opted not to. The answers to this and [the other question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9647/how-do-workers-work-when-i-gain-control-of-them) do overlap but the spirit of the questions seem different to me.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're familiar with [the discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12182/) on this issue, but I strongly feel that questions which garner the same answers should be closed as duplicate.  In this case you literally have the exact same answer...

Comment: @tzenes I was not aware of that; thank you. If you want to close this one, it makes sense to me. I'd vote to close but I lack the rep.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, if your teammate drops from the game, you (and your teammates) gain control of their units. You can even build new units or structures as them by selecting their buildings/workers.

Any resources harvested by the dropped person are split equally among everyone else, and building things for the dropped person are paid for by whoever clicks the button.